# Adjust Entity Reference "Number of values" Based on Role

Tags: entities

There are two roles, standard and premium. I would like the standard role to be able to select up to 10 users via the entity reference field. I would like the premium role to be able to select an unlimited number of users via the SAME entity reference field.

A standard user can upgrade to a premium user, so any nodes they edit after an upgrade would need to allow for additional selections via that entity reference field.

I'm a front end developer, and not too handy with PHP, so ideally I would need to be able to make this functionality via another module and configuration. I'm essentially looking for the functionality of [Field Permissions Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions), but extending it to the number of values a user can select.